# QT QMessageBox default button?

Tags: qt

I've got a `QMessageBox` with `Yes` and `No` alternatives.

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "New update", "There is a new update, do you want to update now?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes) {

} else {

}
```

But for some reason the default answer is always `No`. How can I set the default button to `Yes`

I've tried:

```
reply.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Yes);
```

But cannot get that to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QMessageBox::question` can be passed an extra parameter that has the default value of `NoButton`, and you are not using that parameter, see the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question), so your code will become:

```
reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "New update", "There is a new update, do you want to update now?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No, QMessageBox::Yes);
```